# How to page a View

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a view in my sql server 2005 db.

I'm using Pythons PyMsSQL to select rows form the view. I'm not necessarily selecting all the rows in the view with this select. For example, I might select based on name or date etc.

How can I page this view? That is, how can I select row 0 to 9, or rows 10 to 19 etc.

Thanks for your help,

Barry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the `ROW_NUMBER` window function to

- add a number you can select on
- using an `ORDER BY` date, name or any other column that guarantees the order between subsequent runs.

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Date ) AS RowNum, *
          FROM      AView
        ) AS AView
WHERE   RowNum BETWEEN 1 AND 9
```